# Is 'SELinux enforcing' responsible?

Tags: root-access, selinux

My HTC android mobile is rooted after unlocking the bootloader, but it is with S-ON. When I write some files(I mean copy and paste) inside my '/system' partition for the purpose of applying a 'Mod', it works , but whenever I make a reboot, those files vanish. Is it due to 'S-ON' or is it due to 'SELinux enforced' ? What for is 'SELinux permissive' required?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to S-ON, so changes made to /system while the phone is running is not permanent, and will be reset upon a reboot of the device.  For information on SELinux in Android, review this link https://source.android.com/security/selinux/.

A brief explanation, taken from the above link:

> "With SELinux, Android can better protect and confine system services,
> control access to application data and system logs, reduce the effects
> of malicious software, and protect users from potential flaws in code
> on mobile devices."
>
> "Permissive mode - in which permission denials are logged but not
> enforced."
>
> "Enforcing mode - in which permissions denials are both logged and
> enforced."